# Use PHP in_array with mutli array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to use the same principe that in_array, but with a double array and only search in the first value. Let me explain :

```
$array_1 = [["1","aaa"],["2","bbb"],["3","aaa"],["4","ddd"]]

$array_2 = [["2","bbb"],["3","aaa"],["4","ddd"]]
```

Now i want the function return ["1", "aaa"] because this part is not in the second array. But I want to search difference only with the id (number 1, 2, 3 and 4), not with the text who can be similar, but never the id.

Comment: Did you try [`array_diff`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Are you asking about comparing two arrays, or searching for an element within an array?

Comment: Are they arrays as in: `$array_1 = array(array("1","aaa"),array("2","bbb"),array("3","aaa"),array("4","ddd"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/array_udiff) function:

```
$array_1 = [["1", "aaa"], ["2", "bbb"], ["3", "aaa"], ["4", "ddd"]];
$array_2 = [["2", "bbb"], ["3", "aaa"], ["4", "ddd"]];

$output = array_udiff($array_1, $array_2, function($a, $b){
  if ($a[0] < $b[0]) {
    return -1;
  } else if ($a[0] > $b[0]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
```

Comment: Thank you it's works fine! Now i need the same function but in jQuery , Is it possible?